# error Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) in c

Tags: c

I am trying to order a very large array by the bubble method (to take execution times) and after 40000 data it freezes. If someone could tell me what the error is. Thank you
the data is taken from a text file previously created with 10 million jumbled data

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void bubbleSort(int *arr, int n){
    int i, temp;
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    if(n == 1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        bubbleSort(arr, n-1);
    }
}

int main(){

    double time_spent = 0.0;

    int n, i, num, *Aleatorio, cont = 0;

    FILE *f = fopen("archivo.txt","rt");

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de datos a analizar: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    Aleatorio = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    if(Aleatorio == NULL){
        printf("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    }
    else{
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            fscanf(f, "%d", &num);
            Aleatorio[i] = num;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    /*
    printf("\n\nArray Desordenado : \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ",Aleatorio[i]);
        //cont++;
    }
    */
    clock_t begin = clock();

    bubbleSort(Aleatorio, n);

    clock_t end = clock();
    free(Aleatorio);

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\nArray Ordenado : \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ",Aleatorio[i]);
        cont++;
    }



    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\n\n cont = %d", cont);
    printf("\n\nThe elapsed time is %f seconds", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

I have seen that it is a stackoverflow error, but I have not found what the error could be since a certain amount of data is ordered by me.
the code has to sort up to 10 million pieces of data (I know it will take forever but I have to do it)

Comment: Why is the sort recursive?

Comment: Remember the stack is a few MB (less than whit it would take to have 10 million calls) so unless your compiler optimizes out the recursion this will overflow the stack.

Comment: Do you really want the bubble sort to be recursive? How many recursive calls do you expect? Do you have enough stack space for recursion that deep?

Comment: is recursive because I am asked to do it that way

Comment: Igor S.K. i think that im not enough space for this tipe of recursion and i dont know how to do it really

Comment: @Benja does your code work if `n` is small? But anyway witj  10 million items to sort, bubble sort will probably take forever.

Comment: @Benja it's absolutely pointless to use recursion for an inherently non recursive problem. Ask the person who asked you to do this recursively. You could as well write a recursive program that counts from 1 to 1000000 (recursion here is pointless), you most likely will get a stack overflow as well.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, yes its work with up to n = 30000, more than that it gives an error

Comment: @Benja the only thing you can do here to address the problem is not using recursion. Period.

Comment: Were you asked to use *a* recursive sort algorithm or were you specifically asked to implement a recursive *bubble* sort?

Comment: @Bob__ good catch. Quick sort is typically recursive.  The recursion depth of quick sort is (I think) log2(N) where N is the number of items to sort. Actually this may not quite correct, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326380/quicksorts-estimation-of-recursion-depth for more details

Comment: @Bob__  I was asked to implement a recursive development of the bubble algorithm

Comment: @Benja recursive bubble sort is pointless per definition. Why do they want recursion? And why do they want bubble sort? All this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Jabberwocky all this is to see the execution times of each algorithm, it is a work of the college

Comment: @Benja you need to increase the stack size. This depends on your platform, but for very deep recursions like 10 million items, you'd need a stack size of roughly 100 million bytes which is prohibitive.

Comment: Well, you could implement the recursion in a [different way](https://godbolt.org/z/134erM5q6), but that wouldn't really be a bubble sort anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll see. I will see it